# UserName / FullName as Filter in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have created a pivot table which the source is in another sheet called database and this is connected to a sharepoint list.

In the pivot table, I wanted to set / filter the Caretaker to whoever opened the macro file instead of "All".All of the users open the macro file can be found in the database sheet. I have set the .currentPage = Application.UserName. So whenever they open the file, only their processed items will be displayed. but it gives me an error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub RefreshQuery()

 Dim timestamp As String

 timestamp = UCase(Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss"))

 With Sheets("DATABASE")

    .Range("Table_owssvr").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh
    .Range("Table_owssvr_returned").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh

 End With


With Sheets("SUMMARY")
    With .PivotTables("PivotTable1")
        .PivotCache.Refresh
        .PivotFields("CARETAKER").ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFields("CARETAKER").CurrentPage = Application.UserName
        .PivotFields("CARETAKER").PivotItems("CARETAKER").Visible = False
End With
.Shapes("Rectangle 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "LAST UPDATED:    " & timestamp
End With


End Sub
```

Is it possible that the .currentPage in pivot table will be equal to the Full Name of the user opened the file?

Comment: Try enabling "allow multiple selection" in the page-filter

Comment: I have enabled the allow multiple selection in the filter but it prompts the same error for the application.username.

Comment: Could it be that Application.UserName is not available in the "Caretaker"-List?

Comment: it's not available. Because application.username will get the name of the user in File > General > User name. But it seems it's not getting it and prompting me an error of "Application-defined or object-defined error". I am not sure what causes this error. Maybe this is not allowed.

Comment: Maybe you mean to use Environ("USERNAME") ?

Comment: I also tried to replace application.username to Environ("USERNAME") but gives the same error.